# IE11 stack overflow after receiving partial view response to AJAX POST (doesn't happen in other browsers)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer

This is likely going to be far too vague a question, but I am getting a stack overflow error in IE11 after getting a response from an AJAX POST in a page built with ASP.NET MVC 5.

**SCRIPT2343: Stack overflow at line: 5008**

I sometimes get the error at line 5228.

This works fine in Chrome and Firefox (not an uncommon story). It occurs when I am posting a large form and getting a large partial view back in return. There are hundreds of checkboxes on the partial view sent in the response. It looks like I am getting the complete partial view back and it seems to display fine, but it does seem to truly get messed up because some of the JavaScript stops working afterwards.

The overflow appears to occur in jQuery (though I am only guessing a little as the error does not give much information or point me to the file). If so, it looks related to event handling. I'm wondering if there is any useful way to track events firing? I'm wondering if there is JavaScript in there firing way too many recursive events?

I am using jQuery 3.1.1, but it also happened on an older version I was using (1.12 I believe). I'm also using jQuery UI 1.12.1.

I'm looking for some guidance as to how to debug this. Anything I should be looking for in the IE11 F12 tools? Any other useful tools to use, or anything else to consider or try?

Comment: if you use different versions of jQuery and the line number of the error doesn't change it's unlikely that the error is in jQuery ... also, if you're using minified jQuery, it's unlikely that it has 5228 lines

Comment: @JaromandaX it isn't minified at this point, but I do need to check if the line numbers have changed between versions.

Comment: You can click on the error message in the Console tab of the dev tool to jump to line and column numbers where the error occurred. Then you can place a break point at the line before the error, so that you can break before the error occurs and examine the local variables.

Comment: @RobParsons unfortunately, clicking on the link simply spawns another browser pointing to a generic Visual Studio help page.

Comment: f12>Debug tab, select "Break on all exceptions" from the dropdown (it looks like a stop sign), then (!important) without closing the dev tool (pin it to the IE window if you like), return to your browser and refresh the page.... the debugger will now stop at those errors for you to debug it.